# Handling CSV data encoding to be inserted into UTF-8 Database

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

We have some CSV files that our users will be using and hence the encoding may not be `UTF-8` and will probably be `cp1252` encoding from Windows. I have noticed that if it contains a single quote for example that all data after and including the quote is then stripped off and not inserted into the database.

I tried using the `utf8_encode` function but this just removes the quote, which I don't want to do.

What can I do here so I can make sure that all the correct data is inserted into the database in the correct encoding?

Comment: What SQL request do you use to import data? LOAD DATA INFILE? Post it with the simplest incorrect CSV file example.

Comment: @user4035 It's not loaded straight into the DB, some processing is done on it first. It's gotten through `file` first and then each row is passed through `fgetcsv`.

Comment: can you show the relevant php code and a csv sample, that causes an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try iconv("CP1252", "UTF-8", $string);

regards